# Recursively search a parent->children relationship, applying bool to a branch

Tags: javascript, c#, algorithm, recursion

If I have a tree like this:

```
A
  B
    C
D
  E
F
```

If the user searches for `C`, I want to recursively drill down the tree, set a property on `C` (called `Expanded` for this example) to true... but then also set that property on its parents so `A`, `B`, and `C` would have `Expanded` set to true.

How would I accomplish something like this with recursion?

I have a solution (abstractly) for setting the property on the deepest child in the tree, but when unfolding back out is where I'm having an issue trying to set that property on each of its parent.

Comment: Can you show the actual code?

Comment: Why did you tag this with c# and javascript? Either way, without any sort of structure, this is asking a lot of an answerer, as in order to answer this type of question it would require them to create not only the data structure and naming convention, but also a *proposed* solution as a guess.

Comment: Most people answered it. I just thought of adding how about considering dfs algorithm. A modified version will give you what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code assumes that each `Node` has a collection of child `Nodes`.

The first step is to check if the current `Node` has a match (by `value` in this example).  If it does, then set the `Expanded` property and return `true` to the caller.

Otherwise, iterate the child nodes and recursively call the `DoSearch`.  If any of the child nodes match, then set the `Expanded` property current `Node` and return `true` to the caller.

```
bool DoSearch(Node n, int value)
{
    if (n.Value == value)
    {
        n.Expanded = true;
        return true; // let the caller know that the value was found
    }
    foreach (Node child in n.Nodes)
    {
        if (DoSearch(child, value)) // a child contains the value
        {
            n.Expanded = true;
            return true; // let the caller know that the value was found
        }
    }
    return false; // not found
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need a recursive function to accomplished that. Find the node you want and traverse back to root while setting the expanded property.

```
var runner = FindNode('C');
while(runner) {
   runner.expanded = true;
   runner = runner.parent;
}
```